# how to get release date from google play api using protobuf

Tags: java, python, android, api, protocol-buffers

this project https://github.com/NoMore201/googleplay-api  can used to retreive data directly from google using protobuf like that

```
message AppDetails {
  optional string developerName = 1;
  optional int32 majorVersionNumber = 2;
  optional int32 versionCode = 3;
  optional string versionString = 4;
  optional string title = 5;
  repeated string appCategory = 7;
  optional int32 contentRating = 8;
  optional int64 installationSize = 9;
  repeated string permission = 10;
  optional string developerEmail = 11;
  optional string developerWebsite = 12;
  optional string numDownloads = 13;
  optional string packageName = 14;
  optional string recentChangesHtml = 15;
  optional string uploadDate = 16;
  repeated FileMetadata file = 17;
  optional string appType = 18;
  optional bool unstable = 21;
  optional bool hasInstantLink = 24;
  optional string containsAds = 30;
  optional Dependencies dependencies = 34;
  optional TestingProgramInfo testingProgramInfo = 35;
  optional EarlyAccessInfo earlyAccessInfo = 36;
  optional string instantLink = 43;
  optional string developerAddress = 45;
}
```

it return upload date and many other important information .. but its not returning the releasedate i try to decompile the last version of com.android.vending but they used proguard .. there  is any way to get the release date ??